# Git repo not found

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone a private repo and I know it should prompt me for username and password but I get this message when I run

```
git clone https://github.com/orgname/repo
```

The error is

```
fatal: repository not found
```

Is there a separate command to clone private repos?

Also, when I try to download the zip it cannot be extracted

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloning a private Github repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo)

Comment: Adam, should I prefix https://

Comment: it gives the same error

Comment: what is even more perplexing is that I can download the master but not the branch

Answer (score 0):

You must have at least read access team permissions.

https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization-repository

Comment: i do have the read permissions since I can navigate to the source through github and view the files

Comment: OP have you checked this GitHub resource? https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found

Also are you able to fork the repo?