# Can't pull from private repo

Tags: git, github

I had a public repo at github.com/bclayman/Stats2 which I recently turned into a private repo.

Now, when I SSH into a machine and try to pull from that repo, I get:

error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/bclayman/Stats2.git/info/refs

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: use the ssh uri to pull (assuming your ssh keys are set up in github)

Comment: @pvg Sorry but could you elaborate?  I'm not really sure what you mean by the "ssh uri" (or how I'd check whether my ssh keys are set up in github)

Comment: actually it looks like it could work with https as well. the main problem is that you haven't told git how to authenticate that you're a user with access to that repo. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo

Comment: @pvg So I should be doing git pull git@github.com:bclayman/Stats2.git?  I've not set up any SSH keys...                                                                 When I do the above, I get:                                                                             git pull git@github.com:bclayman/Stats2.git
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Go to your repo and look at the status line above the file listing. there's a drop down there that gives you different access uris - https, ssh, etc. Just set up an ssh key and then clone or pull with the ssh uri it gives you. Probably the simplest thing.

Comment: @pvg So that drop down for ssh says git@github.com:bclayman/Stats2.git  When I run ls -al ~/.ssh, I see that I already have this ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ssh key...

Comment: you need to upload  that public key to github. check their docs.

Comment: @pvg that public key is "already in use" according to github...thanks again!