# How to checkout a private github repository via HTTPS when 2-factor authentication is on?

Tags: git, authentication, github, ssh-keys

At work and on my own computer I normally use github with ssh keys.
I also installed 2-factor authentification via text-message.
Everything works fine.

But when I'm at another computer, where I do not have my ssh key, I'm of course not able to checkout from my (private) repository via the

```
git clone git@github.com:joergi/myproject.git
```

But when I switch to the HTTPS Version I can not checkout via

```
git clone https://github.com/joergi/myproject.git
Cloning into 'myproject'...
Username for 'https://github.com': joergi
Password for 'https://joergi@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/joergi/myproject.git/'
```

Username and password are 100% correct.

Is there any way to use HTTPS , when 2-factor authentication is activated?

Comment: I ran into this problem as well. I ended up just using it as ssh. This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo

Comment: but I don't want to have a ssh key to my repo on someones else computer. no other way?

Comment: @LelandBarton - and it's not really a duplicate. this guy was using the wrong (read only) url - I'm asking if it's generally possible to checkout via HTTPS.

Comment: I figured there was a little bit more to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is documentation from [github](https://github.com/blog/1614-two-factor-authentication) on how two factor auth behaves. It discusses https repositories on the command line. You can generate a `personal access token` and use that to login.

The price of security is a inconvenience. You could temporarily disable two factor auth as well.

Comment: I still use MY GITHUB account. this person doesn't have a github account at all.
I want to check out MY private repo without adding another ssh key.
like using the 2-way-authentification for checking out or something like that