# Cloning: Repository Not Found

Tags: git, github

So I currently have code at the following url: https://github.com/ahcarpenter/stewardship-user

However after executing `git clone git://github.com/ahcarpenter/stewardship-user.git` I'm getting the 'Repository not found' error. I can go to [github.com/ahcarpenter/stewardship-user.git](http://github.com/ahcarpenter/stewardship-user.git) and the repo comes up.

Any thoughts?

Comment: this is no stewardship-user repo in your github

Comment: @Alexan sorry, it's private, should've mentioned that

Comment: [Cloning a private Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538035/240564)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloning a private Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo)

Answer (score 0):

for mac:-

Open keychain access and reset your github credentials.