# Allow cloning of private repository by password for non-GitHub users

Tags: git, github, passwords, clone, private

I want to allow people to clone my private repository by using a password,
even if they are not Github users. Is that possible?

Comment: correct title: NON-GITHUB users

Comment: Check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloning a private Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  GitHub restricts access based on usernames and doesn't provide anonymous access to private repositories using a password.  Anyone who wants to clone your repository from GitHub will need to have their own account and will need to have been added with read permissions on the repository.

Alternately, you can set up a mirror on a server you control with Git and a web server and give out the password there.