# How to deploy private git repo on shared hosting (cpanel)

Tags: git, cpanel

I am trying to deploy my private git repo on cpanel, but I am facing this Error.
[image: cpanel]

I don't have terminal or ssh access to the cPanel, that is why I can not clone git repo with git commands. the only option for me is the git user interface provided by cPanel. and when I use the http address of my repo I face the mentioned error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can clone your project with https instead of ssh

Comment: @bahram only http is provided by our gitlab server and I face the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to clone a private respo. You can only clone public repo using this.

you can go through this [Cloning a private Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo)

although the options present there may be a tad outdated.