# unable to clone data from github to colab

Tags: git, google-colaboratory

I created a colab notbook and write the following codes in colab:

```
%cd drive/My Drive/blabla
!git clone https://...balbalproject.git
```

I was hoping that it will upload the file of blablaproject.git into the colab Google Drive directory: blabla/

But it didn't, and instead i got the following message:

```
Cloning into 'blabla'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/rkbrary/Project-IFT6760A/ does not appear to exist, or perhaps is a private repository. If it's the latter, you need to use the correct form of the URL: see [Cloning a private Github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo)