# Git hub desktop, cloning repository: authentication failed

Tags: github, github-desktop

Using github desktop with a self taught fundamental level of understanding for github.

When I am trying to clone a repository to another computer it pops up with "authentication failed please put in username and password"
After putting in username and password it repeats the process of saying authentication failed.

I feel as though I haven't done much to warrant any problems but the app doesn't even suggest any other problem apart from the username and password possibly being wrong.

What are the steps I should take to fix this?

[image]

Steps I take to create this problem:

1. Make a private repository
2. Try to download the repository on another computer.
3. Put int username and password when it says "authentication failed" - notice it repeats this authentication failed popup.
4. Cry.

Ways I have worked around this:

- Temporarily making my repository public and then downloading it.
- Only working from the computer that created the repository/ when on another persons project only working from one computer.
- Using bitbucket with SSH keys.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo
This might Help.

Comment: Well, i am not cloning via url, i am clonning via github desktop. Surely i should not have to find a work around for a basic button in the main github app?

Comment: if i try via url then it says auth failed : Some common reasons include:
then lists a bunch of reasons that cannot poissible be the cause.

Comment: further, I have generated a token and added an SSH key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authenticity of GIthub could not be established. Not that github could not establish the computers authenticity.

This was likely due to the lack of ports open to acess the computer.
checking for the ssh authenticity and then asking to continue without github confirmed authenticity solved it. in git bash.

This requires the use of an SSH key:

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh
[image]