# Git on new Windows 10 installation does not provide input for credentials

Tags: git, github, repository

I have recently reinstalled windows 10 on my computer, and as such I also reinstalled wamp which I use for my projects.

However, upon trying to download my repositories, I've come to realize that I can only clone the public repos. When cloning a private repo, it says that it's cloning and creates the folder named after the repo but nothing happens next, neither failing nor downloading anything.

What am I doing wrong? The command I run is:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/project.git
```

**EDIT:**

After working with the problem some more, I uninstalled and reinstalled GitBash, although that did not seem to change anything. Lots of commands like git clone, or git pull, did not work just like in the original post; the command was accepted, and the blinking cursor would go on forever without returning anything. I noticed that the whole issue is about not having my credentials set into Windows' "credential manager", which I had visited multiple times since the beginning. It has always been empty of github-related information, so this time I decided to manually add the info, since gitbash never prompted me to add my github credentials.

So, after going to Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials > Add a generic credential then simply entering "https://github.com/" and my email and password, I re-run the command:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/project.git
```

where "project" is a PRIVATE repository, and gitbash proceeded to normally download it. Right after that, I checked back into Windows' credential manager, and found a new "generic credential" input, but this one has the address "git:https://github.com" and the "Persistence" field is marked as "Local computer" instead of "Enterprise" for the one I manually made (both of these fields where assigned automatically).

Apparently, this is not the solution to the ultimate problem of this thread; "Why does git not provide any input for credentials whatsoever", but this solution seems to work so far. So if anyone has an idea for that, please write below!

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/cloning-a-private-github-repo

Comment: How large is the repo?

Comment: There's a bug in the latest Git-for-Windows (2.32.whatever). The bug is absent in 2.30.whatever, and presumably will be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks @torek, I really hope this is it.