# Why am I not able to clone a private repository in which I am a collaborator

Tags: git, authentication, github, git-clone, private-repository

I am a collaborator in one the private github repository. I am able to fork it but when I try to clone it onto my system, it shows a pop up box asking for credentials and even if I enter correct credentials I can't login.

Is it just me or github actually doesn't allow cloning of private repo even if I am a collaborator in it?

Comment: "it shows a pop up box asking for credentials" - this is not an adequate description of the popup window. What platform are you running on? Exactly what `git` software are you running?

Comment: @Dai I am using git bash

Comment: What version of Git Bash? What credential cache provider or credential manager for git are you using? Are you using the GitHub-branded credential manager or the general-purpose manager?

Comment: @Dai I am using general purpose manager

Comment: I have the same exact problem and if you found a solution please share

Comment: I found that question as duplicate here [Clone A Private Repository (Github)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505096/clone-a-private-repository-github/77804882#77804882), and I answered it. [Here is my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77804882/12811519)

Answer (score 7):

You can clone it over `HTTPS`

```
git clone https://github.com/privateRepo/privateRepo.git
```

The prompt will ask for your username password/Authentication Token.

or

```
git clone https://username:token@github.com/user/repo
```

**Note** :- Support for password authentication was removed [[link]](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/). Please use a personal access token instead of password if it does not work.

Comment: "git clone https://username:token@github.com/user/repo" this one works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem and realized that I am mistakenly adding an unnecessary `<username>` into the command.

**Solution**:

We should have or create personal access token. You can refer [creating a personal access token link](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) to create one.
And the command should be:
`git clone https://<personal_access_token>@github.com/<your account or organization>/<repo>.git`

**Be careful**

I was mistakenly adding an extra `<username>` which is not seen in the repository link. We should simply use the repository link which **already includes** `account user name or organization name`.

For a repository link something like [this](https://github.com/mustafasdet/python.git) `https://github.com/mustafasdet/python.git`, we should simply put `personal_access_token` after `https://`.  And here is the command:

`git clone https://ghb_qrghF29zGGmfd9w54hdf56vdnbWo90K82@github.com/mustafasdet/python.git`

Comment: Your reference link and assistance are good resource for me.

Comment: @Dev Conductor, thanks for the feedback and I am glad it is useful.

Comment: @Mustafa SDET - I hope that's not your real Personal Access Token?

Comment: @Timmah, sure it is a fake one:)

Answer (score 0):

If you can fork it, you should be albe to clone it.

> even if I enter correct credential

Make sure to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as your password, instead of your actual GitHub account password.
This is because of "[Token authentication requirements for Git operations](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/)" from Dec. 2020.

Comment: @ I have used personalized token already. But I am able to clone only public repo. Even if I am a collaborato in private repo I am not able to clone it

Comment: @Anjali Is it a recent PAT, with the right scope?

Comment: @Anjali What is your git version, and the output of `git config --global credential.manager`?

Comment: my git version is 2.33.0.windows.2 and 'git config --global credential.manager' is not showing any output

Comment: @Anjali For testing, can you try and create a new private repository (not a fork), and see of you can clone it (still using your PAT)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the repo, you can do this in 5 steps:

1. Copy the "https" to clone, go to git bash and enter:

2: `git config --global user.name "yourUserGit"`

3: `git config --global user.password "yourPasswordGit"`

4: `git clone "https://github.com/user/repoName.git"`

5: `cd repoName`

And be happy :)